# Jquery ajax call in a loop, wait for every call to be completed

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, .when

I have this ajax function, that returns an array of prices:

```
function get_date_price(checkdate, type_r) {
    return $.ajax({
             type: "POST",
             url: "hotels/get_check_date_price", 
             data: {id: $("#hotel_id").val(), checkdate1: checkdate, type_r1: type_r},
             dataType: "JSON",  
             cache:false,
             success:
             function(data){
             }
    });
}
```

Then I want to call this function in a loop and calculate the total price, I use `$.when` to wait for every ajax call to be completed, so that the returned price is correct (else it returns 0)

```
var total = 0;
for(var i = 0; i < $("#nights").val(); i++){
    $.when(get_date_price("02/09/2016","Chambre Single")).then(function (v) {
        total += parseFloat(v[1][0].price);
        console.log(total);    
    });
}
```

When the loop contains, for example, 5 iterations, all works perfectly, when the number of iteration increases, some requests  return 403! :

[image]

**PS:** I have remarqued that in a private navigation, the code is working without errors!

Comment: Any reason why you don't calculate the total price at the server?

Comment: It's much more complicated than what I have posted, I'll see if I can calculate the total price at the server, but also I want to know how to make this code work correctly, with this mthode!

Comment: Maybe the server limits the number of concurrent calls from the same ip

Comment: Yes, I'll try it now..